# How to calculate probability using T distribution in R and When to use T distribution

Tags: r, t-distribution

Can someone help me to solve below question using R programming.

A Government  company claims that an average light bulb lasts 270 days. A researcher randomly selects 18 bulbs for testing. The sampled bulbs last an average of 260 days, with a standard deviation of 90 days. If the CEO's claim were true, what is the probability that 18 randomly selected bulbs would have an average life of no more than 260 days

With the data above provided i used T distribution to calculate probability using below formula in R

```
  qt(0.95,17) = 1.73
```

Probability using T distribution = (1.73) * 90/sqrt(18) = 36.69

Is this proper way to solve and can someone please tell me is there is function to get probability for T distribution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Part of your question can be answered immediately: this cannot possibly be the proper way to solve the problem because no probability can equal $36.69.$

Comment: @durga: Let your null hypothesis be that $\mu=270$ and bulb life is normally distributed around this mean with unknown variance. Now, $\bar{x}$, under the null would follow certain distribution. you need to calculate, $Pr(\bar{x} \leq 260)$. This should be straight forward if distribution is known. But since variance is unknown, enters t- distribution. Now you know a function of $\bar{x}$ that follows t-distribution, under null. So convert $Pr(\bar{x} \leq 260)$ in terms of your t-statistic now. That should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume this is a normal distribution. But there is a process you need to consider:

You want to compare the sample mean [image] to the reported mean [image]. In this case you are comparing [image] to [image]. To do this, we need to consider that the Student's T distribution approaches the standard normal distribution when the samples get large. Because the samples are relatively small here, (n = 18), we use the T-distribution. To calculate the t-statistic use

[image]

Once you have calculated that, then you can use `pt()` function in R. The full view of this is to:

`p <- pt((260-270)/(90/sqrt(18)), 18)`

Where we calculate the probability `p` using the formula and the `(260-270)/(90/sqrt(18))` is the t-statistic and `df = 18`. In general, the calculation for `df = n-1`; however, in R the `df = n` since to calculate the distribution, instead of using `n`, the software uses `n+1`.

Comment: -1 There are several problems with this answer.  The most salient is the incorrect information about `pt`.  Subtler, but more important, is that it doesn't correctly answer the question.

Comment: Understood above calculation for T distribution but i have one more doubt, the question says

what is the probability that 18 randomly selected bulbs would have an average life of no more than 260 days

What does this no more than mean? should we consider with 1-p.

Thanks

Comment: Wow. That was a complete misread on my part. Thanks for the call out @whuber.

Comment: @whuber: can you please explain how it doesn't answer the question? durga: "probability that 18 randomly selected bulbs would have an average life of no more than 260 days" should mean $Pr(\bar{x} \leq 260)$. Based on that the answer seems correct I think.

Comment: The misuse of `pt` stems from an incorrect account of the function: it is perfectly conventional in its use of degrees of freedom, whose value is 17 in this case.  However, there appears to be no justification for the Student t distribution: the respondent is asked to assume "the claim is true:" that is, to assume the underlying distribution has a mean of 260 and SD of 90.  The sampling distribution of the mean will then have close to a *Normal* distribution, not a Student t distribution.